# What is the difference between a ref and a global variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a functional component called `HelloWorld` sitting in a `HelloWorld.js` file. Let's say I want to keep track of the mouse position without triggering a render again.

As a beginner, I know two options:

```
let mousePosition = null;

const HelloWorld = () => {
  // ...
  mousePosition = aNewPosition;

  const handlerReadingPosition = () => {
    console.log(mousePosition)
  }
}
```

and

```
const HelloWorld = () => {
  const mousePositionRef = useRef(null);
  // ...
  mousePositionRef.current = aNewPosition;

  const handlerReadingPosition = () => {
    console.log(mousePositionRef.current)
  }
}
```

Are these two block of codes equivalent? If I declare a variable within HelloWorld, it will be erased on each render, hence the `useRef`.

Is there any "rule" to declare variables inside `HelloWorld` rather than just before?

Comment: Think of what happens if your component is used multiple times in the same page (not just rendered multiple times with different states)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can think of a `ref` as an instance variable of a class.

The global approach will break when you have multiple instances of the component rendered.

Comment: What happens if you only have one instance? Does it make any difference to store the value in a ref or anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm creating a javascript file. I want to store a value in a variable and this variable has to be used across many other functions.

For Eg: I'm having an input field. So initially the input tag is empty. In my javascript file I'm having a variable declared as `userName`. With a key up function I'm getting the value from the input field on every key stroke and assigning it to the variable.

Now there is another function which uses my name for some other reason. Now since my `userName` is globally declared I can use it any where.

```
var userName                                            //This is the global variable
$('#userNameDiv').on('keyup',function(){               //Jquery method
   userName = $('#userName').val()                     //The variable is referenced here
   let temp_userName = $('#userName').val()            //Local variable as it is defined within a block and has let key word
})

function(){
   console.log(userName)                              //Since userName is globally declared it will be console logged.
   console.log(temp_userName)                         //will be undefined as it is a local variable
}
```